POST Error when making a move on a chess board
I have a frontend chess board where each piece is movable/draggable to a square and the moves are to be transferred over to the backend via the post api.
FRONTEND:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chess Board</title>
  <style>
    #chessboard {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .square {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer; 
    }

    .black {
      background-color: #769656;
    }

    .white {
      background-color: #eeeed2;
    }

    .piece {
      font-size: 40px;
      cursor: move; 
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-drag: none; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chessboard"></div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const chessboard = document.getElementById("chessboard");
      let draggedPiece = null;
      let prevRow, prevCol;

      // Function to generate chessboard
      function generateChessboard() {
        const piecesOrder = ['♜', '♞', '♝', '♛', '♚', '♝', '♞', '♜'];
        const pawns = '♟'.repeat(8);

        for (let row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            const square = document.createElement("div");
            square.classList.add("square");
            square.id = `square-${row}-${col}`; // Assign unique id to each square
            if ((row + col) % 2 === 0) {
              square.classList.add("white");
            } else {
              square.classList.add("black");
            }
            square.dataset.row = row;
            square.dataset.col = col;

            const piece = document.createElement("span");
            piece.classList.add("piece");

            // Set up initial positions for white and black pieces
            if (row === 0) {
              piece.textContent = piecesOrder[col];
            } else if (row === 1) {
              piece.textContent = pawns[col];
            } else if (row === 6) {
              piece.textContent = pawns[col].toUpperCase(); // Capitalize for black pawns
            } else if (row === 7) {
              piece.textContent = piecesOrder[col].toUpperCase(); // Capitalize for black pieces
            }

            piece.draggable = true; // Make pieces draggable

            piece.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart); // Add dragstart event listener

            square.appendChild(piece);
            chessboard.appendChild(square);
          }
        }
      }

      // Drag-and-drop functions
      function dragStart(event) {
        draggedPiece = event.target;
        prevRow = draggedPiece.parentElement.dataset.row;
        prevCol = draggedPiece.parentElement.dataset.col;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ""); 
      }

      chessboard.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver); 
      chessboard.addEventListener("drop", drop); 

      function dragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const targetSquare = event.target.closest(".square");
    const targetPiece = targetSquare.querySelector(".piece");
    if (!targetPiece) {
        targetSquare.appendChild(draggedPiece);
        draggedPiece = null;
    } else {
        const sourceSquare = draggedPiece.parentElement;
        const fromSquare = sourceSquare.id; 
        const toSquare = targetSquare.id;
        makeMove(fromSquare, toSquare); 
        targetSquare.removeChild(targetPiece);
        targetSquare.appendChild(draggedPiece);
        sourceSquare.appendChild(targetPiece);
    }
    const newRow = targetSquare.dataset.row;
    const newCol = targetSquare.dataset.col;
    console.log(`Piece moved from (${prevRow},${prevCol}) to (${newRow},${newCol})`);
}


      // Generate the chessboard
      generateChessboard();
    });


    // Function to make a move on the chessboard via the backend server
function makeMove(fromSquare, toSquare) {
    fetch('/move', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fromSquare, toSquare })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
  
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
  </script>

BACKEND:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Allow requests from any origin
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Allow certain HTTP methods
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    // Allow certain HTTP headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    // Allow credentials (if needed)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    
    // Move to the next middleware
    next();
  });
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
let port=2000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port ${port}");
});

// Function to initialize the chessboard with starting positions
function initializeChessboard() {
    return [
        [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 3, 5], // Black pieces in the first row
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], // Black pawns in the second row
        Array(8).fill(0), 
        Array(8).fill(0),
        Array(8).fill(0),
        Array(8).fill(0),
        [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11], // White pawns in the second-to-last row
        [15, 13, 14, 16, 17, 14, 13, 15] // White pieces in the last row
    ];
}

// Array to store the current state of the chessboard
let chessboardState = initializeChessboard();

// Route to get the current state of the chessboard
app.get('/chessboard', (req, res) => {
    res.json(chessboardState);
});

// Route to make a move on the chessboard
app.post('/move', (req, res) => {
    const { fromSquare, toSquare } = req.body;

    // Parse the coordinates of the squares
    const [fromRow, fromCol] = parseCoordinates(fromSquare);
    const [toRow, toCol] = parseCoordinates(toSquare);

    // Check if the move is valid
    if (!isValidMove(fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 'error', message: 'Invalid move' });
    }

    // Make the move on the chessboard
    chessboardState[toRow][toCol] = chessboardState[fromRow][fromCol];
    chessboardState[fromRow][fromCol] = 0; // Clear the source square

    // Send a response indicating the move was successful
    res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Move processed successfully' });
});

// Function to parse coordinates from square notation (e.g., 'a1' to [0, 0])
function parseCoordinates(square) {
    const col = square.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
    const row = 8 - parseInt(square[1]);
    return [row, col];
}

// Function to check if a move is valid
function isValidMove(fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol) {
    return true;
}


Whenever I run the program and check the DEVTOOLS on the frontend side, the post api never seems to work when I make a move on the chessboard. I keep getting the 500 status code error.

Does the backend print an error in the console? Please include it in the question. If not, add an error handler and print the error to console.
